# Contentful BlogPost: How can I display different category blogs on 2 different container using gatsby graphql

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

Hi I'm very new on using gatsby and contentful for cms. I just want to display different category blog post on the same page. Is there a way that this can be possible? Below is the code on how I show the loop of blogpost and also the graphql that gets the data from contentful(not really sure). Sorry for the bad coding. Is it possible that I make 2 different container with blogpost with different category?

```
    const siteTitle = get(this, 'props.data.site.siteMetadata.title')
const posts = get(this, 'props.data.allContentfulBlogPost.edges')<div className="row">
<div className="col-lg-12 text-left">
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
    {posts.map(({ node }) => {
        return (
            <ArticlePreview article={node} />
        )
    })}
</div> 
export const CommunityQuery = graphql
    query CommunityIndexQuery {
    site {
        siteMetadata {
        title
    }
    }
allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }) {
    edges {
        node {
          title
          slug
          publishDate(formatString: "MMMM Do, YYYY")
          tags
          heroImage {
            fluid(maxWidth: 350, maxHeight: 156, resizingBehavior: SCALE) {
              ...GatsbyContentfulFluid_tracedSVG
            }
          }
          description {
            childMarkdownRemark {
              html
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by using 2 different queries in your `communityQuery`. It should look like:

```
export const CommunityQuery = graphql
    query CommunityIndexQuery {
    site {
        siteMetadata {
        title
    }
    }
categoryOne: allContentfulBlogPost(
   filter: {category: {eq: "category one name"}}
   sort: { fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }) {
    edges {
        node {
        //your fields
        }
      }
    }
categoryTwo: allContentfulBlogPost(
   filter: {category: {eq: "category two name"}}
   sort: { fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }) {
    edges {
        node {
        //your fields
        }
      }
    }
}`
```

*Note: keep in mind that you provided a generic query so I don't know what fields or what filters you should put to filter by category, this is just an approach.*

This will generate 2 objects that you can retrieve easily by `props.data.categoryOne` and `props.data.categoryTwo` (that queries are aliased, it's a good way to clean up your code, if don't, your object may look like: `props.data.allContentfulBlogPost`).

Comment: i used your codes but it throw an error 
ERROR #85901  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

`vipspng: libpng read error
vips2png: unable to write to target`

Comment: I cant seem to make my codes show up like yours. my greatest apologies for that. Can you tell me what is wrong? @ferran buireu


`export const CommunityQuery = graphql
query CommunityIndexQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    categoryOne: allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }) {
      edges {
        node {
     //
        }
      }
    }
    categoryTwo: allContentfulBlogPost(sort: { fields: [publishDate], order: DESC }) {
       edges {
        node {
     //
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

Comment: also is there a way to filter it by the content of the field? for e.g the first query only shows up blogs which category is CategoryOne and the other query will only show up blogs which category is CategoryTwo? Thanks

Comment: This is what I told you in my answer (in the note below the snippet). You didn't provide your schema or data structure so I don't know where are the categories placed (inside each node I would guess). I've updated my answer adding how a filter should look like but you will need to clarify and focus more on your question.